# how to embed/stream internet radio on a website?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I can use, for example, something like

**`<object id="MediaPlayer" width="300" height="50"  classid="CLSID:22D6f312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"  standby="Loading Live Player components..."   type="application/x-oleobject" CODEBASE="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/
mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=6,4,7,1112">`**

to embed a mediaplayer. But the problem is if I navigate to another webpage on the site it stops and then users have to select thier channel and play it again. I want it as something like, if users are homepage they select their fav channel and play it. so later if they are on, say, page123.php, they radio shouldn't stop playing. Can you help me sorting it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options:

- Frames/Iframes, with one (tiny/invisible) frame containing the player and the other the next page - not recommendable for usability and SEO reasons (Users can't bookmark pages anymore, among other things)
- A pop-up window.

Comment: yes, i did try frames and know the negatives .. any other idea than Pop up windows??

Comment: Unfortunately, no. As far as I can see, short of programming a custom browser toolbar, this is all you can do.